# New-AzApiManagementSubscription A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a subscription for an API using the cmdlet New-AzApiManagementSubscription. Got the error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'".
Following is the code.

$envID = "DEV"

$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "RGNM" -ServiceName "APIM-SRVC"

Write-Host "Creating the product"

#Create Product.

New-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $apimContext -ProductId "Prjname-$envID-Product" -Title "Prjname-$envID-Product" -Description "APIM Product for Prjname " -ApprovalRequired $False -SubscriptionRequired $True -State "Published"

Write-Host "Creating the Subscription"

#Create Subscriptions

New-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $apimContext -SubscriptionId "Prjnam-test-Subscription" -Name "Prjnam-testcomp-$envID-Subscription1" -Scope "/products/Prjname-$envID-Product" -AllowTracing $True -State "Active".

Product is created successfully, but the Subscription is throwing the error.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple explanation for this line below,

`New-AzApiManagementSubscription -AllowTracing $True`

The cmdlet `New-AzApiManagementSubscription` has a parameter named `AllowTracing`, and you've specified a value of `$True` for this parameter

`AllowTracing` is not a `boolean` parameter and doesn't require a `True` or `False` input